# How to give more power to a USB device (error -110)?

Tags: usb, usb-drive, power-management, external-hdd

I’m trying to mount an external hard drive (2.5", USB, no separate power supply) on Debian 7, but it gives me (in `dmesg` as well as when trying to boot with the device connected) errors like:

> `device descriptor read/64, error -110`
>   `device not accepting address 7, error -110`

While capturing errors from `dmesg`, after several minutes, it was mounted automatically and I could copy some files, then it was gone again, after which it mounted a second time (this time for only a few moments). But after that, nothing.

Searching for `error -110` leads to several posts suggesting that the device probably doesn’t get enough power. Seems plausible, at least to a layman like me. Unfortunately, I don’t have access to a different PC to try it. But as I managed (randomly?) to mount it with my PC, it should be possible to do it again, so I wonder:

**Is there a way to give more power to the USB port where the device is connected?**

Could I disable *something* on my system to save power which would then be available for the device?

(I’m not looking for a permanent solution; I just want to get the data and never see the device again.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy a powered USB hub, less than $20 at places like Staples or Best Buy.  You're not going to get the system to push more power out of a port than it is already doing.